# Intellij giving me an error when it builds project from gui form

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm somewhat new to Java and using intellij to learn gui. If I understand right, intellij doesn't build the source code for your gui when you design it, you have to select build->buildproject. It auto generates the code but provides things that give me an error in my code. Everywhere this shows up "com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints", it's red in the editor.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameGUI {
    private JPanel contolPanel;
    private JLabel labelImage;

    {
// GUI initializer generated by IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer
// >>> IMPORTANT!! <<<
// DO NOT EDIT OR ADD ANY CODE HERE!
        $$$setupUI$$$();
    }

    /**
     * Method generated by IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer
     * >>> IMPORTANT!! <<<
     * DO NOT edit this method OR call it in your code!
     *
     * @noinspection ALL
     */
    private void $$$setupUI$$$() {
        contolPanel = new JPanel();
        contolPanel.setLayout(new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager(1, 2, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), -1, -1));
        contolPanel.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
        contolPanel.setAlignmentY(1.0f);
        contolPanel.setAutoscrolls(false);
        contolPanel.putClientProperty("html.disable", Boolean.FALSE);
        labelImage = new JLabel();
        labelImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/java.png")));
        labelImage.setText("Label");
        contolPanel.add(labelImage, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_WEST, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_NONE, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, null, null, null, 0, false));
        final com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.Spacer spacer1 = new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.Spacer();
        contolPanel.add(spacer1, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_HORIZONTAL, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, 1, null, null, null, 0, false));
    }

    /**
     * @noinspection ALL
     */
    public JComponent $$$getRootComponent$$$() {
        return contolPanel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `IDEA_HOME\redist\forms_rt.jar` file to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).

You can switch off source code generation and use the default option for GUI Designer which will instrument the bytecode so that you don't see the generated code at all in the editor.

Comment: thanks. Sorry, just so I understand when you say IDEA_HOME are you referring to where I have intellij stored on my computer?

Comment: Yes, it's the directory where you have IntelliJ IDEA installed.

Comment: I don't seem to have that file. Also, I have that file and cannot find forms_rt.jar

Comment: Please show the screenshot of the files you have in IntelliJ IDEA installation directory and redist subdirectory.

Comment: I can't seem to find where it's installed. All I see is that it's in my applications folder but that is the launcher right?

Comment: `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/`

Comment: I've been following other tutorials on where to find installed programs but intellij isn't showing up. System information -> Software->installations. It's no where to be found. Iooked in my library folder and it's not there either.

Comment: Uh, I'm an idiot. I found it. Thanks CrazyCoder. I'm sorry and please excuse my lack of knowledge, I'm still learning. I appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: On my IntelliJ 2021.2.3 the file is here: <IDEA_HOME>/lib/forms_rt.jar

Answer (score 3):

For those using maven, adding dependency helps:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
    <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```